# write contents of an environment to document and toc

Tags: table-of-contents, environments

I want to write the contents of an environment to the document and the toc. Here's a MWE hacked to look (almost) like what I need.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{g}
{}
{\newline}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{First}

\begin{g}
first goal first chapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{first goal first chapter}
%\addtocontents{toc}{first goal first chapter} %% yields error message
\end{g}
\begin{g}
second goal first chapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{second goal first chapter}
\end{g}

Chapter contents here \ldots

\chapter{Second}

\begin{g}
first goal second chapter
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{first goal second chapter}
\end{g}

Chapter contents here \ldots

\end{document}
```

That produces this toc:

[image: the actual toc]

What I'd like is this (with no hyperref links for the extra lines):

[image: the desired toc]

Problems I don't know how to solve:

- Most important: how can I capture the write twice behavior in the
  environment definition so that I don't have to specify the extra toc
  line with cut and paste each time?
- Secondary: Why does `\addtocontents` produce an error when commented 
  in? (An answer to this might solve the entry formatting and link problem.)

I can use the `xparse` package to define the environment if that makes for an easier solution.

Comment: The `environ` package gives you access to the body of the environment using a macro `\BODY`.  You could use that to write the TOC line in the start or end code of the environment.

Comment: @ScottH. Works like a charm almost. Solves the double write problem, but the second goal incarnation in the first chapter in the document has an extra indentation not in my MWE. The `addtocontents` error continues. You can post this as an answer I'd vote up, but not accept quite yet.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code you got with @ScottH. 's help so that others can build on it ;)

Comment: @tochecz egreg's answer below appeared before I saw this good idea, which I will remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When LaTeX is reading the table of contents file it expects specially formatted paragraphs. Here's a way to do what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@goal[1]{%
  \addpenalty{\@highpenalty}%
  \vskip \z@ \@plus \p@ 
  \begingroup
  \parindent\z@
  \rightskip\@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth 
  \leavevmode #1\nobreak\hfil\nobreak\null\par 
  \penalty\@highpenalty
  \endgroup} 
\newcommand{\goal}[1]{%
  \par\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\l@goal{#1}}\noindent#1\par}
\NewEnviron{goal*}{\goal{\BODY}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{First}
\goal{first goal first chapter}
\goal{second goal first chapter}

\bigskip

Chapter contents here \ldots

\chapter{Second}
\begin{goal*}
first goal second chapter
\end{goal*}

\bigskip

Chapter contents here \ldots

\end{document}
```

If the goal text is not long, perhaps the command form is preferable. Otherwise use `goal*`.

The macro `\goal` writes to the `.toc` file using `\addtocontents`, because `hyperref` patches `\addcontentsline` so that it creates a link. We write `\l@goal{<goal text>}` and then the macro `\l@goal` does essentially the same as `\l@chapter`, which is responsible for typesetting the chapter title in the ToC.