# Create all queries in separate file like \listoffigure

Tags: macros, automation

I would like to print all the queries collect from the `article` and need to print in article opener page. How do achieve this?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{threecolumn}
\begin{document}
\jnltype{37}
\querieson %%% if it's on query texts need to display on first page article
\title[The challenge of growth hormone deficiency]{The challenge of growth hormone deficiency diagnosis and treatment during the transition from puberty into adulthood}
\author{Balaji\/}
\address{Molecular Endocrinology Unit, USA}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
The main effect the following author names with Frontiers if they would like their names on the article abstract page and PDF to be linked to their Frontiers profiles. Please\query[-350pt]{Kindly confirm if the details appearing in running title, article title, author names, affiliations, correspondence address, email ID, abstract and keywords are fine.} ensure to do so before submitting the proof corrections of GH therapy in childhood is to stimulate linear growth: therefore\query{Please add "$\ldots$ to the reference list.} the primary objective of GH replacement therapy in growth hormone deficient (GHD) children is to achieve adult height within the genetic target range.

In addition, GH plays a key role in the regulation of body composition and metabolism and its deficiency in adulthood has been associated with reduced lean body mass \query[-300pt]{Please confirm if the affiliations of the authors  are fine.} and bone mineral density (BMD), increased visceral adiposity, abnormal lipid profile, decreased muscle strength, cardiovascular risk, and impaired quality of life  body homeostasis to require lifelong GH administration in subjects with permanent GHD. As many subjects are no longer GH-deficient when retested at the end of linear growth, the correct reassessment of childhood-onset GHD (CO-GHD) is crucial for selecting patients who need lifelong GH therapy.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might be able to adapt this answer to meet your needs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60738/write-contents-of-an-environment-to-document-and-toc

Comment: Is there any news here? I don't even understand the question.

Comment: I tried with a crystall ball, but still i didn't understand the question. Since there is no feedback .. i vote to close as unclear.